# cassandra query and performance (I have 3 column A,B,C in my table and i would like to search all three column)

Tags: cassandra

I have some questions about query in cassandra,please help me out . Thank .
I have 3 column A,B,C in my table
and i would like to search all three column , maybe two and maybe one .
My question is :
How many table i should create? and what is the key on each table? 
The best performance is my destination  , I have three node in my system .

Answer (score 1):

If your table is small, doing a table scan can have acceptable performance. You can add secondary indexes to the other columns. However, if you find you need multiple secondary indexes, it suggests that your table schema is inappropriate for Cassandra. The form of your question (I have a table I want to query...) suggests you have followed an RDBMS approach, which does not work well for Cassandra. The recommended approach is to start with the queries you want to perform, then design the tables so those queries are efficient, designing denormalised tables if necessary. Rather than creating a normalized data model.

Comment: Hi Friend
"The recommended approach is to start with the queries you want to perform, then design the tables so those queries are efficient"
Yes . i am understand but my question is how can i design the table with my search condition ( i would like to search all three column , maybe two and maybe one).
Sorry , I'm new with cassandra .and i have no idea to what to do.

Comment: Maybe i think we just create key((A,B),C) with C is datetime.
Any idea?